# missing sass-loader, css-loader dependecies quasar/vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, quasar-framework

I recently begun to work on a ongoing project. I cloned the repo, runned "npm install", everything worked fine, but when I tried to run the server I got this:

[missing dependecies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVMc6.png)

trying to run the sugested code didn't work. I also tried installing and reinstalling: css-loader, vue-loader, sass, node-sass and sass-loader.

The error text:

```
98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin



ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                      10:31:48
These dependencies were not found:

* -!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!../styles/sass-framework/colors.scss in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.auto-import.js?kebab!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Login.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=26084dc2&lang=scss&scoped=true&
* -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./styles/sass-framework/colors.scss in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.auto-import.js?kebab!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&  

To install them, you can run: npm install --save -!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!../styles/sass-framework/colors.scss -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./styles/sass-framework/colors.scss
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "scale-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/traverse": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/types": "^7.10.2",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "1.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~2.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a custom dependency that was missing:

```
./styles/sass-framework/colors.scss
```

sass-framework is a repo itself and had to be added manually inside the project.